# Transferring value from another column in ifelse within dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have dataframe `dd` (dput at bottom of question):

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   Date [5]
  Date     keeper
  <chr>    <lgl> 
1 1/1/2018 TRUE  
2 2/1/2018 TRUE  
3 3/1/2018 FALSE 
4 4/1/2018 FALSE 
5 3/1/2018 TRUE  
6 5/1/2018 TRUE
```

Note it is already grouped by Date. I'm trying to create another column that will turn "keeper" to TRUE if there's only one row in the group, and otherwise keep the value of keeper. That seemed fairly simple, but when I tried this, I got the following result:

```
dd %>% mutate(moose=ifelse(n()==1,TRUE,keeper))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Date [5]
  Date     keeper moose
  <chr>    <lgl>  <lgl>
1 1/1/2018 TRUE   TRUE 
2 2/1/2018 TRUE   TRUE 
3 3/1/2018 FALSE  FALSE
4 4/1/2018 FALSE  TRUE 
5 3/1/2018 TRUE   FALSE
6 5/1/2018 TRUE   TRUE
```

Note that rows 3 and 5 have the same Date, so they should have just retained what's in keeper for the new column -- but they both got turned to FALSE. What am I missing?

Expected output:

```
  Date     keeper moose
  <chr>    <lgl>  <lgl>
1 1/1/2018 TRUE   TRUE 
2 2/1/2018 TRUE   TRUE 
3 3/1/2018 FALSE  FALSE
4 4/1/2018 FALSE  TRUE 
5 3/1/2018 TRUE   TRUE
6 5/1/2018 TRUE   TRUE
```

(note row 5)

Here's the dput for the dataframe:

```
dd<-structure(list(Date = c("1/1/2018", "2/1/2018", "3/1/2018", "4/1/2018", 
"3/1/2018", "5/1/2018"), keeper = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), vars = "Date", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0L, 1L, c(2L, 4L), 3L, 5L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L), biggest_group_size = 2L, labels = structure(list(Date = c("1/1/2018", 
"2/1/2018", "3/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "5/1/2018")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), vars = "Date", drop = TRUE, indices = list(0L, 1L, 2L, 
    4L, 3L, 5L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
    Date = c("1/1/2018", "2/1/2018", "3/1/2018", "3/1/2018", 
    "4/1/2018", "5/1/2018"), keeper = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, TRUE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
), vars = c("Date", "keeper"), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("Date", 
"keeper")), .Names = "Date"), .Names = c("Date", "keeper"))
```

ADDENDUM:

As I continue to play with this dataframe, I discovered that if I first create a column `n` using `add_count`, and refer to that column in my `ifelse` instead of to `n()`, I get the result I'm looking for. What's causing this? Why isn't `n()` giving me the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a recycling effect.  For `ifelse`, we need the arguments to have the same length.  The `length` of `n()` is 1.  The second argument `TRUE` length is 1.  So, there is a mismatch in `length` with the third argument 'keeper' which is of `length` `n()`.  This creates the imbalance in recycling.  The OP mentioned in the addendum that if a column is created, then the issue is not there.  Reason is that once the column is created, the `length` of 'n' column is not 1, it is the `n()`.

```
dd %>% 
   mutate(moose = ifelse(rep(n(), n()) == 1, TRUE, keeper))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Date [5]
#  Date     keeper moose
#  <chr>    <lgl>  <lgl>
#1 1/1/2018 TRUE   TRUE 
#2 2/1/2018 TRUE   TRUE 
#3 3/1/2018 FALSE  FALSE
#4 4/1/2018 FALSE  TRUE 
#5 3/1/2018 TRUE   TRUE 
#6 5/1/2018 TRUE   TRUE
```

---

Also, as the `length` of `n()` is 1, we can use `if/else`

```
dd %>% 
    mutate(moose = if(n()==1) TRUE else keeper)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Date [5]
#  Date     keeper moose
#  <chr>    <lgl>  <lgl>
#1 1/1/2018 TRUE   TRUE 
#2 2/1/2018 TRUE   TRUE 
#3 3/1/2018 FALSE  FALSE
#4 4/1/2018 FALSE  TRUE 
#5 3/1/2018 TRUE   TRUE 
#6 5/1/2018 TRUE   TRUE
```

Comment: Nope, still gives me the same result.

Comment: Also, see the addendum I just added.

Comment: I see. That feels so strange! Thanks.

Comment: @iod If I use `ifelse`, then I would try to make the lengths same without relying on the recycling.